# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, mas por quê?

Tags: sql, oracle

Já estava com problemas na criação desta tabela em relação a hora, mas finalmente, com ajuda consegui resolver o problema. No fim acabei me deparando com outro erro, mas não entendo o por que.

Segue o código:

```
create table horario (
codhorario number (8) primary key,
horainicio DATE to_char (horainicio, 'hh24:mi'),
horafim DATE to_char (horafim, 'hh24:mi'));
```

Meu erro:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Eu pesquisei na internet sobre e acabei encontrando que poderia ser parêntesis a mais ou a menos, mas que também poderia ser erro de sintaxe. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Qual o motivo de chamar a função to_char durante a criação de uma tabela?

Comment: Hmm eu não sei exatamente como implementa-la, pensei que fosse nesse formato. Como seria então?

Comment: Você quer um campo para salvar horas?

Comment: Isso, 2 no caso de inicio e fim. Mas pelo que parece a função to_char está no lugar errado.

Comment: `to_char` retorna uma string, mas o campo é um `DATE`, então já não faz sentido isso. Se quer guardar apenas as horas, [existem algumas alternativas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/42084)

Comment: Como dito acima e sendo só hora eu faria como CHAR/VARCHAR2 , uma TRIGGER poderia validar o conteúdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O correto seria armazenar a data completa:

```
create table horario ( codhorario number(8) , horainicio DATE, horafim
DATE );
```

Caso você queira somente hora e minuto depois.
Através do select vc pode obter os dados.

```
select to_char(horainicio , 'hh24:mi') as horainicio ,
       to_char(horafim, 'hh24:mi') as horafim,
from horario
```